# How we can pass HTML tags inside Power Automate Asana Create Task V2 action

Tags: power-automate, asana, asana-api

We have this create Asana task action inside our automated Power Automate flow:

[image]

now i am trying to pass HTML tags inside the Description field,... but on ASANA the Description will show the html tags as is not as formatted text.. any advice?

Here is the created task inside Asana:-

[image]

any advice how to format the Asana Description field using Power Automate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asana uses **Markdown** to format rich text, not HTML. So you could try MD instead in the Power Automate action.

Source: https://help.asana.com/hc/en-us/articles/14142327738779-Text-formatting-in-Asana

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what will MD do exactly ?

Comment: MD is MarkDown 